# Resize bitmap to the particular height in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap, android-bitmap

I know this question is asked before but when I try that solution they give me bitmap of dimension 750 x 1125 when I set a particular height of 1000

This is my code to resize bitmap height 1000

```
public Bitmap captureBitmapFromYuvFrame(VideoFrame i420Frame) {

        VideoFrame.I420Buffer i420Buffer = i420Frame.getBuffer().toI420();
        ByteBuffer[] yuvPlanes = { i420Buffer.getDataY(), i420Buffer.getDataU(), i420Buffer.getDataV() };
        int[] yuvStrides = { i420Buffer.getStrideY(), i420Buffer.getStrideU(), i420Buffer.getStrideV() };
        YuvImage yuvImage = i420ToYuvImage(yuvPlanes, yuvStrides,
                i420Frame.getBuffer().getWidth(),
                i420Frame.getBuffer().getHeight());

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, yuvImage.getWidth(), yuvImage.getHeight());

        // Compress YuvImage to jpeg
        yuvImage.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, stream);

        // Convert jpeg to Bitmap
        byte[] imageBytes = stream.toByteArray();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(imageBytes);
            ImageDecoder.Source src = ImageDecoder.createSource(buffer);
            try {
                bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(src);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        }

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(i420Frame.getRotation()); // Apply any needed rotation
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                true);

        return resizeToWidthRatio(bitmap,1000);
    }


 public static Bitmap resizeToWidthRatio(Bitmap bm, int height)
    {
        float ratio = (float)bm.getWidth() / (float)bm.getHeight();
        int width = (int)(height * ratio);
        return resize(bm, width, height);
    }

    public static Bitmap resize(Bitmap bm, int width, int height)
    {
        int oldWidth = bm.getWidth();
        int oldHeight = bm.getHeight();

        // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
        float scaleWidth = ((float)width) / oldWidth;
        float scaleHeight = ((float)height) / oldHeight;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // recreate the new Bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, oldWidth, oldHeight, matrix, true);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

I try this but the result bitmap dimension is 750x1125, I want a height of 1000, not 1125 so can you please suggest the way that I can achieve the  "any widthx1000" this dimension.

Comment: `Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, oldWidth, oldHeight, matrix, true);` Shouldn't you instead of `oldWidth` and `oldHeight` just use `width` and `height`? You are just recreating a bitmap of the same width and height like it was before.

Comment: when i put width and height instead of oldwidth and height I got this error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()

Comment: ,Please show with which parameter values you call your function. And also tell the resolution of original bitmap.

Comment: update the code please check

Comment: In captureBitmapFromYuvFrame() i call the resizeToWidthRatio() fun
by        return resizeToWidthRatio(bitmap,1000);

Comment: Please refresh the page something it's not showing updated code

Comment: Resolution of original bitmap?

Comment: 480 x 720 dimension

Comment: Please add Log.d statements everywhere to log the value of variables. In that way you can follow the calculation. Post the log lines so we know it too.

Comment: `480 x 720 dimension` You should put that on the first line of your post. And then tell that you wanna ENLARGE it. Write a good post please.

Comment: I log the value in rezise()
width = 750 height =1000 scale width = 1.5625 scale height =1.5625

Comment: Have you ever checked what 720*1.5625 would be?

Comment: i just want to resize bitmap height for any bitmap

Comment: Yes. But let us handle this one first. `Have you ever checked what 720*1.5625 would be?` You got what you asked for.

Comment: yeah that height what i get after resize

Comment: And did you ever use a calculator to calculate the scale? Well tell us... Where do things go wrong? What is it that you calculate wrong?

Comment: yesh it's 0.72 for height if i want 1000 height

Comment: 0.72 will NOT enlarge. 1.5625 enlarged too much.

Comment: What is 1125/720? And what is 1000/720?

Comment: 1.5 and 1.3 for those two

Comment: thanks buddy i got your points thanks for helping me I'm frasher at android

Comment: Your scale calculation goes wrong where you mix float and integer. Thats all. Just cast all to float first. And log, log and log, so you see. Check all with a calculator at hand.